# ST_Dump not working with geometry_dump

Tags: postgis

I am trying to ST_Dump a geometry_dump column comprised of points and paths in PostGIS 2.0 using

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom FROM pointdump
```

However, I get the error message 'function st_dump(geometry_dump) does not exist'

I thought that ST_Dump would dump a geometry_dump column into its constituent parts? Or is there another method I can use? Eventually, I want to draw lines between these points to create rectangles.

This column was created by using this function I discovered online elsewhere and ran on a simple polygon:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION st_dumppoints_plpgsql(geometry)
  RETURNS SETOF geometry_dump AS
$BODY$DECLARE
 m integer;
 g geometry;
 n integer;
 p geometry_dump%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  IF GeometryType($1) LIKE 'MULTI%' THEN
    FOR m IN SELECT generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries($1)) LOOP
      p.path[1] := m; -- use to store Multipolygon number
      g := ST_Boundary(ST_GeometryN($1, m));
      FOR n IN SELECT generate_series(1, ST_NumPoints(g) - 1) LOOP
        p.path[2] := n; -- use to store Point number
        p.geom := ST_PointN(g, n);
        RETURN NEXT p;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
  ELSE -- It is not a MULTI- geometry
    g := ST_Boundary($1);
    FOR n IN SELECT generate_series(1, ST_NumPoints(g) - 1) LOOP
      p.path[1] := n; -- use to store Point number
      p.geom := ST_PointN(g, n);
      RETURN NEXT p;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  RETURN;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your geom seems to be geometry_dump already , so no need to dump it.

something like : `select geom as id , geom.path as path , geom.geom as part_of_geom, from xxxx`
(not tested)

should return all what you want

or : `select a.id a.path ST_DUMP(a.part_of_geom).path, ST_DUMP(a.part_of_geom).geom   from (select geom as id , geom.path as path , geom.geom as part_of_geom, from xxxx) as a` 
(not tested)

might do the job

(if not then i didn't understand question)

Comment: thanks, I'll try those. just to be clear though, when i try to export it the shapefile exporter says it doesn't have a geometry column so i wanted to dump the geom and path elements into another table as they are held together currently in the geometry_dump column

Comment: your query didnt work for me